# SSH from public IP to non-public IP after connection established vice versa

Tags: sockets, ssh, network-programming

I have a "mini computer" that uses 3G/4G modem for networking. My ISP doesn't assign public IP for it so there's no way to make an SSH connection directly to it.

I only need it to have the SSH-connection with my home computer. For my home computer I can have a public IP (or rather do some port forwarding from my router) and I also can use dynamic DNS service with it.

So.. If I would set my "mini computer" to connect my home computer every now and then (which it can thanks to dynamic DNS), would it be somehow possible to SSH back to the device since there obviously already is a valid socket/route between them?

Home computer's OS is Win10 and other one's is somewhat modified Raspbian.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su].

Comment: @Kenster Might be a bit on the gray area. I was thinking about writing my own socket listener and then somehow reverse the connection as an SSH tunnel, but probably there already exists a better solution that doesn't involve programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSH to create a tunnel back to your system, i.e.

```
ssh -R2222:127.0.0.1:22 remote-host
```

will connect to remote-host per SSH and opens a tunnel on this host port 2222 back to your local system where it then ends in 127.0.0.1:22, i.e. your SSH server.

Comment: Apparently the answer for my question is "Reverse SSH Tunneling". Now up & running. Thank you!